# tread 1: exc_bad_acces (code=1, adrress=0 x 10) Filter Application

Tags: xcode, swift, core-image

When I test the app the thread appears in where it says class AppDelegate. The thread that appears is "tread 1: exc_bad_acces (code=1, adrress=0 x 10)"

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        return true
    }
```

Here is the code for my app.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var dogImageView: UIImageView!
   let context = CIContext(options: nil)
    @IBAction func ApplyFilter(sender: AnyObject) {

    let inputImage = CIImage(image: dogImageView.image!)


        let randomColor = [kCIInputAngleKey : (Double (arc4random_uniform(314)) / 100)]

        let filteredImage = inputImage?.imageByApplyingFilter("CIHueAdjust", withInputParameters: randomColor)

    let renderedImage = context.createCGImage(filteredImage!, fromRect: (filteredImage?.extent)!)

    dogImageView.image = UIImage(CGImage: renderedImage)

    }


    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage, editingInfo: [String : AnyObject]?) {

        print("Picked image")

        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)


        dogImageView.image = image   
    }

    @IBAction func importImage(sender: AnyObject) {
        let image = UIImagePickerController()
        image.delegate = self
        image.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
        image.allowsEditing = false

        self.presentViewController(image, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: `filteredImage!` is something to check. Are you sure it isn't nil? Also this `(filteredImage?.extent)!` Anywhere you use !, be absolutely sure that it isn't nil.

Comment: Also, I would suggest checking `dogImageView.image!`